# ActiveRecord design for Appointment Scheduling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Finding no plugin/gem that would work as an appointment scheduler in rails I'm trying to roll my own solution out.

Basic requirements I have are:

- Doctor/Laywer/whoever provides days they are open and how many people can make appointment for same spot (1..2..3)
- Appointments are 30 minute basis
- Users choose a date that is open and make an appointment
- one spot is decreased from the total time.

I am trying to come up with a Design for this as a rails app and need some help.

- doctor model with name, ph #, address etc
- appointment model with different time frames between 8-6 (30 minutes apart). `eightThirty:int eightThirtNine:int` ..etc
- Doctor has_many Appointments

I am not able to put everything in perspective as to how the models should associate themselves?

Comment: Hey Anthony, I'm trying to design something similar to what you described.  Just wondering if you could add some learnings from your experience (what you did, what you would have done differently)?